# R: is there an R equivalent for df.info() of pandas (Python)?

Tags: python, r, pandas, types

I would like to know if there is a way of displaying all the data types of my data set on R like you can do on pandas with df.info().

I'm aware I could use

```
names(data)
```

and then for each individual feature do

```
class(data$Feature)
```

However, I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Are you looking for `str(data)` or `summary(data)` ?

Comment: or `dplyr::glimpse(data)`

Comment: @RonakShah str(data), that's' exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`str` and `summary` may give you information about the data that you have.

For example, with in-built `mtcars` dataset.

```
str(mtcars)
#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
# $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

```
summary(mtcars)

#      mpg             cyl             disp             hp       
# Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1   Min.   : 52.0  
# 1st Qu.:15.43   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.8   1st Qu.: 96.5  
# Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :196.3   Median :123.0  
# Mean   :20.09   Mean   :6.188   Mean   :230.7   Mean   :146.7  
# 3rd Qu.:22.80   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:326.0   3rd Qu.:180.0  
# Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :472.0   Max.   :335.0  
#      drat             wt             qsec             vs        
# Min.   :2.760   Min.   :1.513   Min.   :14.50   Min.   :0.0000  
# 1st Qu.:3.080   1st Qu.:2.581   1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:0.0000  
# Median :3.695   Median :3.325   Median :17.71   Median :0.0000  
# Mean   :3.597   Mean   :3.217   Mean   :17.85   Mean   :0.4375  
# 3rd Qu.:3.920   3rd Qu.:3.610   3rd Qu.:18.90   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
# Max.   :4.930   Max.   :5.424   Max.   :22.90   Max.   :1.0000  
#       am              gear            carb      
# Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
# 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:2.000  
# Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :2.000  
# Mean   :0.4062   Mean   :3.688   Mean   :2.812  
# 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
# Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :8.000
```